# Adding the objects in an array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I wrote an algorithm that takes the first two and the last two objects in an array and adds them together. If they do add together, it returns 2. If they don't add together, it checks to see if the second and third objects add up and equal the last two objects. So basically if I have the array [2,3,9,4,1] then it checks to see if 2+3=4+1. In this case, yes, so It would 2. In this array [2,3,6,4,5] 2+3!=4+5 so we would move onto check if 3+6=4+5 and since it is we return 2. Now if there are no two objects that when added together can be equal [0,1,2,3,4] then it returns -1.

Here it is below :

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
{
    [arrayOfNumbers addObject: @(arc4random_uniform(10))];
}
NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfNumbers);
int totalOfLastValues = [[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:[arrayOfNumbers count] - 2]integerValue] + [[arrayOfNumbers lastObject] integerValue];

int mostRecentValue = [arrayOfNumbers[0] integerValue];
for (int i = 1; i < [arrayOfNumbers count]-3; i++) {
    int one = mostRecentValue;
    int two = [arrayOfNumbers[i] integerValue];
    mostRecentValue = two;

    if ((one + two) == totalOfLastValues) {
        NSLog(@"2: Because %@ + %@ = %@ + %@",arrayOfNumbers[i],arrayOfNumbers[i+1],arrayOfNumbers[[arrayOfNumbers count] - 2],[arrayOfNumbers lastObject]);
        break;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"-1: Because %@ + %@ != %@ + %@",arrayOfNumbers[i],arrayOfNumbers[i+1],[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:[arrayOfNumbers count] - 2],[arrayOfNumbers lastObject]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if 9+0=4+5, it says it's not equal to it and then it says the next number sequence is equal to 4+5. For example, here are my NSLog's:

```
2014-02-07 18:54:18.170 [34341:70b] (
    9,
    6,
    6,
    1,
    2,
    0,
    0,
    9,
    7,
    1,
    5,
    9,
    9,
    4,
    5
)
2014-02-07 18:54:18.171 [34341:70b] -1: Because 6 + 6 != 4 + 5
2014-02-07 18:54:18.172 [34341:70b] -1: Because 6 + 1 != 4 + 5
2014-02-07 18:54:18.173 [34341:70b] -1: Because 1 + 2 != 4 + 5
2014-02-07 18:54:18.173 [34341:70b] -1: Because 2 + 0 != 4 + 5
2014-02-07 18:54:18.174 [34341:70b] -1: Because 0 + 0 != 4 + 5
2014-02-07 18:54:18.174 [34341:70b] -1: Because 0 + 9 != 4 + 5
2014-02-07 18:54:18.174 [34341:70b] 2: Because 9 + 7 = 4 + 5
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error.  You are starting with your array index at 1 instead of 0, so you need to subtract 1 in your `NSLog`.  Change your `NSLog` statements to the following.

```
if ((one + two) == totalOfLastValues) {
    NSLog(@"2: Because %@ + %@ = %@ + %@",arrayOfNumbers[i-1],arrayOfNumbers[i],arrayOfNumbers[[arrayOfNumbers count] - 2],[arrayOfNumbers lastObject]);
    break;
} else {
    NSLog(@"-1: Because %@ + %@ != %@ + %@",arrayOfNumbers[i-1],arrayOfNumbers[i],[arrayOfNumbers objectAtIndex:[arrayOfNumbers count] - 2],[arrayOfNumbers lastObject]);
}
```